# SQL - Searching a table using another table's column as criteria

Tags: sql

I have table B with bcust(4-digit integer) and bdate(date) columns. I also have table C with ccust(4-digit integer) and cdate(date). I want to show the records from table c where cdate occurred after bdate.

Comment: Look up the concept of Joins, that should put you on the right path, there will be loads of examples. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I guess, maybe you're looking for this?

```
SELECT c.*
       FROM c
            INNER JOIN b
            ON b.bcust = c.ccust
               AND b.bdate < c.cdate;
```

I assumed, that the records are linked via the `bcust` and `ccust` columns.

Answer (score 0):

Although you did not mention anything on how the records in both tables are related, I guess that records are related if `bcust = ccust`.

Then something like this should do what you want:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM tableC c
  INNER JOIN tableB b ON c.ccust = b.bcust
WHERE c.cdate > b.bdate
```